# Number of ways to select a president and a secretary with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Solve using addition principle: A committee composed of Jesse, Bianca, Ray, and Lily is to select a president and a secretary. How many selections are there in which Jesse is president or not an officer?

I cannot understand how to solve such questions. By far I only know that since ordering does matter in this case it will be solved using permutations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @NormalHuman I wrote out everything the book had now thanks! and since the book says solve using addition principle I am not sure if i want to mislead the users by giving the permutations formula and not focusing on the addition principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: These two outcomes (Jesse is president, or Jesse is not an officer) are mutually exclusive. How many possibilities are there where Jesse is president? (That's almost trivial to count). How many possibilities are there where he is not an officer at all? (That's only slightly harder - it's as if Jesse didn't exist in the problem statement).

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I am trying to understand what your hint means. I may have to add the possibilities of jesse becoming the president with the possibilities of him not being an officer at all. Yet, I cannot understand how to calculate the possibilities.

Comment: Yes, you need to add them. If Jesse is president, how many possibilities for the pair of officers?

Comment: Since there is only one position ( president ) and one person for that position I am guessing the possibility of jesse becoming the president is 1.

Comment: You're making this harder than it is. If Jesse is already president, how many possibilities are there for secretary?

Comment: P(3,1)? , I am really sorry, P&C has always been my weak spot.

Comment: Yes. Any of the other three people can fill the secretary spot. Now, for the other one. If Jesse is not an officer, how many people are there to fill the two spots? And in how many ways can they do it?

Comment: P(3,2) ? and I am guessing 6 possible ways

Comment: That's right (although you shouldn't have to guess: three possibilities for president, and then two for secretary).

Comment: So my final answer is going to be P(3,1) + P(3,2) + 6?, since I have to use the addition principle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32437/discussion-between-rogerl-and-luke).